# geoip.location doesnot work with modified indexnames sent via logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

`geoip.location` is of `geo_point` datatype when an event is sent from logstash to elasticsearch with default indexName. As `geoip.location` has `geo_point` datatype, i can view the plotting of location in maps in kibana as kibana looks for `geo_point` datatype for maps.
[image]

`geoip.location` becomes `geoip.location.lat`, `geoip.location.lon` with `number` datatype, when an event is sent from logstash to elasticsearch with modified indexName. Due to this i'm not able to view the plotting of location in maps in kibana.

i don't understand why elasticsearch would behave differently when i try to add data to a modifiedIndexName. is this a bug with elasticsearch?

[image]

For my usecase i need to use modified indexname, as i need new index for each day. The plan is to store the logs of a particular day in a single index. so, if there are 7 days then i need to have 7 indexes that contains logs of each day (new index should be created based on currentdate).

i searched around for solution, but i'm not able to comprehend and make it to work for me. Kindly help me out on this

**Update (what i did after reading xeraa's answer?)**

In the devtools in kibana,

`GET _template/logstash` - showed the allowed patterns in  `index_patterns` property along with other properties

i included my pattern (dave*) inside `index_patterns` and triggered the `PUT` request. You have to pass the entire existing `body` content (which you would receive in the `GET` request) inside `PUT` request along with your required `index_patterns`, otherwise the default setting will disappear as the `PUT` api will replace whatever data you pass in the `PUT` body

```
PUT _template/logstash
{
  ...
  "index_patterns": [
    "logstash-*","dave*"
   ],
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd guess that there is a template set for the default name, which isn't happening if you rename it.

Check with `GET _template` if any match your old index name and update the setting so that it also gets applied to the new one.